# How to remove "⍰" from parent cells with collapsed child cells in MMA 11.3?

Tags: formatting, cells, version-11.3

I like to work with notebooks and collapse cells containing computations.  This gives me a manuscript-like feel for the notebook, and I like the aesthetics of it.  MMA 11.3 introduced a new "feature" that now places a ⍰ symbol after the text in the parent cell.  It's easiest to show an image of the code:

[image: Open and Closed Cells MMA 11.3]

This was definitely not there in MMA 11.2.  Does anybody know how to turn off the "question-mark-in-a-box"?

Comment: This is the group opener. I guess your system doesn’t have the right guillemet symbol. You can disable these with `ShowGroupOpener->False`. The feature doesn’t always play well with stylesheet anyway.

Comment: Thanks!  The symbol is there in my system (OSX High Sierra), but not sure why it doesn't show properly.   However, your answer let me in the proper direction.  It looks like the values for ShowGroupOpener are "None", "InLine", "InsideFrame" and "OutsideFrame". For some reason, when 11.3 opened my notebook created in a prior version of MMA, the default changed to "InLine" for all the cells.  Changing it back to "OutsideFrame" or "None" fixes the issue.  Many thanks.